# Ignoring directories in earlier commits

Tags: git, gitignore, git-commit

For all my future commits I ignore a directory because I don't have to keep track of the changes there. In that directory is a bunch of images and since I've earlier for a lot of commits included that directory, my repository is more than 270MB. Can I somehow remove the image directory from my earlier commits to decrease the filesize of the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by first using the command written by [cforbish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646106/cforbish).

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf images' HEAD
```

This removed the files from the commit history but didn't change the filesize of the repository. To do that I ran these commands, found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data#cleanup-and-reclaiming-space).

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/

git reflog expire --expire=now --all

git gc --prune=now
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this on [here](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-a-git-repository) and this should work for you (will take a while):

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf images' HEAD
```

Comment: keep in mind that this rewrites history and thus makes everyone who forked/cloned your code unhappy. but that aside it is the way to go

Comment: It removed the files from the commit history but it didn't effect the filesize of the repository.

Comment: run git's garbage collection or clone your filtered repo.